# Why does my bufferedreader only read every second line?

Tags: java, list, reader, buffered

i have a bufferedreader like this:

```
BufferedReader br = BufferedReader(new FileReader(("Output/pointsSorted.txt")));

    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(br.readLine());
    }
    br.close();
}
```

but it only reads every second line and i dont understand why.

This is the file where the reader reads from:

```
bendsan: 1000
gotr_gotey: 87
lordelain: 87
nightbot: 87
vellsain: 87
r3l10n: 86
skalrayi: 85
brom13: 84
llecrezzef: 84
cloudinger: 74
littleangelswing: 60
n3belmacht: 43
mrscandy_: 32
sluckzz: 31
elboy717: 30
assassinenfan: 18
msurai: 18
woischdesdu: 16
daspaddy: 14
sirfullmetal: 10
daranun: 1
```

and this is the output:

```
gotr_gotey: 87
nightbot: 87
r3l10n: 86
brom13: 84
cloudinger: 74
n3belmacht: 43
sluckzz: 31
assassinenfan: 18
woischdesdu: 16
sirfullmetal: 10
```

as you can see every second line is skipped.

Comment: Every `readLine` consumes one line, including call in `while` condition so you are doing it twice in each iteration but printing only result from second call.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're printing `br.readLine()` instead of `line`, therefore reading 2 lines per each iteration of the loop (but printing only one).

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = BufferedReader(new FileReader(("Output/pointsSorted.txt")));

    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){ // line 1
        System.out.println(br.readLine()); // line 2
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Line 1 reads a line from the file and stores it in `line`. Then line 2 reads a new line from the file and outputs it. So the first line is read into `line`, then the second line is printed out, then the third line is read into `line`, then the fourth line is printed out, and so on.

You probably wanted this:

```
BufferedReader br = BufferedReader(new FileReader(("Output/pointsSorted.txt")));

    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `readline()` twice - once inside the `while`'s condition (and then ignoring the result) and once inside its body. Just remove one of the calls, and you should be OK. E.g.:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line); // Use the value of line populated in the while's condition
}
br.close();
```